# What is the difference between Q_WS_* and Q_OS_* in Qt?

Tags: qt

What is the difference between Q_WS_* and Q_OS_* in Qt and when would you use one over the other? I understand that OS is defined on an operating system, and WS is defined for a window system, but I can't see when you'd use one over the other. Wouldn't Q_WS_MAC and Q_OS_MAC be the same, for example? What's the general rule and could I have some example use cases for each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple. You use `Q_OS` flagging when you need operating system specific code and `Q_WS` when you need window system specific code.

As an example, UI for Maemo devices (`Q_WS_MAEMO_5`) often needs to be different from Linux desktop but both are still `Q_OS_LINUX`.

Answer (score 4):

As you know, WS is for Window System, whereas OS is for Operating system.
Under Q_OS_MAC, you could be running Qt with Q_WS_X11, for instance.

Unless you're testing for some feature (or defect) specific to a WS, you probably are looking for OS.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that Q_WS_MAC is no longer defined in QT 5 and you must use Q_OS_MAC, as noted here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-issues.html